# Indexing an image in-between already made content

Tags: css, html, z-index

I have a pre-code page coded as follows:

```
    <div id="linearBg">
            <div id="wrapper">
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                    <div class="navigation"></div>
                    <div class="video"></div> 
                    <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Where linearBg is a gradient background, the back board of the website.
Wrapper is the container for the inner div's, and the rest are content oriented.

So I've already implemented this with styles and all sorts, but the thing is I want to add:

```
<div class="watermark"></div>
```

Underneath/behind both the content and video div, sort of like a reverse watermark,

I've tried z-indexing but I'm not an expert. Could you guide me on to do make this possible?

---

http://jsfiddle.net/nEWCP

All I need is to get the watermark behind both the video and content div's.

Comment: Post a working example on http://jsfiddle.net with your current CSS.

Comment: Sorry for taking my time, here is the jsfiddle you requested :http://jsfiddle.net/nEWCP/ , so all I need is to get the watermark behind both the video and content div's. Thanks and sorry for taking so long to reply.

Comment: @Christophersson Friend I cann't understand you, please post all code.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/yXTYM/3/

The trick is:

- `position: relative` on the video and content div
- `position: absolute` on the watermark div and no positioning, so that it starts where the previous element (nav) ended
- `height: 100%` on the watermark so that it spans to the bottom of the wrapper
- `overflow: hidden` on the containing div so that the watermark doesn't extend below it

Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I don't think that you would even need a new HTML element. If you want a "reverse watermark" as you've described it, it sounds like you want a different background behind the content and video elements. Something different from the gradient.

Really all you need to do is define a class in your CSS that adds the watermark when you need it.

Here's [a basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlieholder/MpuzY/). The orange color simulates your watermark behind only the video and content.

```
.watermark { background: url('/path/to/watermark.png'); }

<div id="linearBg">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="navigation"></div>
        <div class="video watermark"></div> 
        <div class="content watermark"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for that, i'll have a try of implementing it! i'll let you know

Comment: the thing is, I'd like the watermark to overlap the gradient too! So it basically goes out of the wrapper div and over the linearBg div

Comment: If your watermark is transparent, it will. The transparency in the watermark will allow the gradient to be visible as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/82saE/

I think I have what you're after - a wrapping element that mirrors the dimensions of `linearBg` - giving you a gradient background with a repeating image as well.